# Is a shadow launch in AWS Lambda possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

## What is a shadow launch?

Shadow launch means that you launch the new version but it not yet gets live traffic. The traffic of the old version gets 1:1 copied into the the new one and so you can measure the performance and results of the new function against the old one without influencing the live system.

## Tried approach

I already tried building something like that myself with a "Proxy" function that async calls the new function and dumps the results and sync calls the old one returning its results.

The problem are side effects: If both functions do something e.g. in DynamoDB there could be an invalid state in the DB because of the shadow launch.

## Goal

I want to test new code versions of a particular lambda function.

## Intended usage Example

I have a function that calculates Fibbonacci [recursive](https://gist.github.com/meghakrishnamurthy/331bd9addab3dbb1b6a23802b1c6845e#file-fibonacci-java-L43-L48) and stores the result with a timestamp in DynamoDB in my live system.

This function is called via [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) as one in a chain of many.

As it should be more efficient to calculate it [iterative](https://gist.github.com/meghakrishnamurthy/331bd9addab3dbb1b6a23802b1c6845e#file-fibonacci-java-L20-L33) I implement the function with this new algorithm.

Now I want to test the assumption that the new function is more performant than the old one.
So I shadow deploy it AWS lambda to get the actually live traffic as testing data.

### Problem

With the current tooling I found it is only possible to execute the function twice and thereby create two entries in DynamoDB which I consider an unwanted side effect as my data in the DynamoDB is in an unintended invalid state.

If I mock the external services in the new function, it may always be more performant than the old one as the time-expensive external services are not access and thereby my result would be incorrect.

## Question

Is it possible to shadow launch a new version of an AWS lambda function without these side effects?

Comment: Could you elaborate more, what you are trying to achieve here, what are the things you want to test in this 'shadow' version comparing to prod version? There could be a different  approach rather than copy from one to another.

Comment: Added more context and a concrete example

Comment: You are just having one production database at hand on AWS?

Comment: How does your lambda function get the traffic? ex: api-gateway or with different service event?

Comment: The lambda function is chained from within AWS Step Functions and gets its traffic from there

Comment: Are you using CloudFront as an entry point to your system? If so I can provide a potential option/solution.

Comment: Make the shadow write to a separate storage and compare results for both calls.

Comment: @F_SO_K currently I do not use cloudfront as entry point, but would you be so kind to share your solution anyways? Maybe it can be adapted to my problem

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use Lambda Aliases and routing configuration to send a portion of traffic to a second function version. Basically, the event source is now mapped with an alias ARN of the function, then you can configure traffic weights to route most % of it through the current version, and the other % with the new version, for example.

Some info and examples in the documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html

Comment: I know about that, but that is a so called "Canary Launch" and not a Shadow Launch I intend to implement. Partly sending traffic is not the problem, the 1:1 copy and the sideeffects of that is the hard part

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single Lambda to send event into a AWS SNS which distribute events into different SQS queue. Then your old version and new version handle different SQS queue, but those events are exact the same.

Comment: Would work but still has the same big problem with the side effects as stated in the question

Comment: @SimonFrey then why not make each lambda write to a different dynamo table? If they both run at the same time and write to the same table - of course you will have those 'side-effects'.

Comment: @LLL yes, might be the only solution to require the a different DB

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you use CloudFront, so a good option might be to use a Lambda@Edge function on the CloudFront request.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-a-b-testing

Basically, you can execute some code every time you get a CloudFront request. The link I have sent is about A/B testing, meaning you choose to send a request to instance A OR B. But there is nothing stopping you sending the request to A AND B.

This would be completely transparent to the user. You could deploy both versions, have both versions executed (or in some proportion), and the user experience would be the same.